I cant get Microsoft graph API to work with IMAP after basic authentication was depracated
I have a couple outlook accounts, but Microsoft is getting rid of basic authentication. I'm trying to use OAUTH2 and I've made an app on azure with the permissions:
IMAP.AccessAsUser.All,
Mail.Read, offline_access, User.Read
I'm logging into each account using playwright, and getting an authorization code then using the API to get a refresh token and access token. For some reason, even after reading the docs and researching for hours, I still cant log into IMAP using the access token.
The first code block is my script and the 2nd code block is the error/terminal output.
if you are wondering why i used a bunch of {ms} in f strings its because this message kept triggering the sp4m filters :/
    import base64
    import requests
    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
    import imaplib
    
    
    #CLIENT_ID = ""
    #CLIENT_SECRET = ""
    ms='https://graph.microsoft.com/'
    TENANT_ID = "common"
    AUTHORITY_URL = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}"
    TOKEN_URL = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000'
    url=auth_url = (
        f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
        f"?client_id={CLIENT_ID}"
        "&response_type=code"
        f"&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}"
        "&response_mode=query"
        f"&scope={ms}IMAP.AccessAsUser.All "
        f"{ms}Mail.Read offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read")
    
    
    def exchange_code_for_token(code):
        payload = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
            "scope": [
            f"{ms}IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
            f"{ms}Mail.Read",
            "offline_access",
            f"{ms}User.Read"
        ],
        }
        response = requests.post(TOKEN_URL, data=payload)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            tokens = response.json()
            return tokens
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Error fetching token: {response.text}")
    
    with open('emails.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
    
            AUTHORIZATION_CODE = None
            entry_email = line.split(',')[0].strip()
            entry_pass = line.split(',')[1].strip()
            with open('logs','r') as f:
                if entry_email in f.read():
                    continue
    
            with sync_playwright() as playwright:
                browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
                context = browser.new_context()
                page = context.new_page()
                context.set_default_timeout(7500)
                page.set_default_timeout(7500)
                page.goto(url)
                page.get_by_label("Enter your email address").fill(entry_email)
                page.get_by_label("Enter your email address").press("Enter")
                page.get_by_test_id("i0118").fill(entry_pass)
                page.get_by_test_id("i0118").press("Enter")
                page.click('#declineButton')
                page.wait_for_load_state()
    
                try:
                    page.click('input[type="button"][name="ucaccept"]', timeout=5000)
                except:
                    pass
    
                try:
                    AUTHORIZATION_CODE = page.url.split('code=')[1].split('&')[0]
                except:
                    print('Could not find Auth code, moving to next email')
                    context.close()
                    browser.close()
                    continue
    
                context.close()
                browser.close()
    
                tokens = exchange_code_for_token(AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                ACCESS_TOKEN=tokens.get('access_token')
                REFRESH_TOKEN=tokens.get('refresh_token')
    
                imap_host = "outlook.office365.com"
                imap_port = 993
    
                auth_string = f"user={entry_email}\x01auth=Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}\x01\x01"
                auth_string = base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode()).decode()
    
                imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, imap_port)
                imap.debug=4
    
                imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
                imap.select("inbox")```
    

Error:
09:49.21 > b'CLLJ1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2'
09:49.22 < b'+ '
09:49.22 write literal size 223609:49.23 < b'CLLJ1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
'09:49.23 NO response: b'AUTHENTICATE failed.'


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78817877/authenticate-an-imap-using-auth2-0-microsoft-entra-id-not-working-for-outlook#comment138962661_78817877   If you are using v2 endpoints you need the https://office.outlook.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All etc endpoints, NOT the graph ones.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

ms='"https://graph.microsoft.com/' The way you're defining this string, it contains a literal double-quote.  This may or may not be related to your problem.

@JohnGordon thank you for pointing this out, although I added this in stack overflow and it wasn't in my original script, so its not this.

@Max thank you this seems correct after re-reading the docs and the other thread. Although after removing the other scopes and just keeping IMAP.AccessAsUser.All, and replacing the endpoints i still dont get a JWT token like the docs says I should, after posting the auth code to the v2 endpoint. Do you have any idea as to why this could be?
